# undefined variable Codeigniter and invalid argument supplied foreach read database

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I was following the [instruction](http://www.papatlimo.com/2011/09/simple-crud-with-codeigniter.html) to get the entire record from table, and load them into html table. this is the model

```
private $namatabel;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $namatabel='ms_kategori_material';
}

function read()
{        
   $sql = $this->db->get($this->namatabel);  

   if($sql->num_rows() > 0)
    {     
        foreach($sql->result() as $row)
        {  
            $data[] = $row;  
        }     
        return $data;  
    } 
    else 
    {  
        return null;  
    }  

}
```

then use the `read()` function on controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_kategorimaterial');
}

function index()
{
    $data['c_row'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->read();
//pass the c_row into the views  
    $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial', $data);  
}
```

to display them on the views

```
<?php  
$no = 1;   
foreach ($c_row as $row) { ?>  
    <tr id="row">  
        <td id="no"><?php echo $no;?></td>  
        <td id="judul"><?php echo $row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa;?></td>  
        <td id="kategori"><?php echo $row->Nama_Material_Jasa;?></td>                 
    </tr>  
<?php  
    $no++;  
}  
?>
```

but then I got an error saying, undefined variable `c_row` and invalid argument supplied `foreach()`. I thought I have sent the `c_row` variable through the `c_kategorimaterial/index` and copy pasting `foreach` statement. what went wrong ?

Comment: I think the method in your model is returning null! why don't you `print_r($data)`in your model and check?

Comment: Just wondering, why are you putting your result into that array? if you didn't do that foreach loop in your model, and instead return $sql->result(), you'd save the time spent on looping through the results before returning it. Since you're just making another copy of the array.

Comment: @JonathanChow i have no idea about what i wrote, since i just copy-pasted the code, and understand them by each line of code

Comment: your model is returning null is my guess. update your controller and model sample code to show us the `class` keyword. AKA - how are they named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Check whether you are getting the data right by using `print_r($data)`. If that went wrong,you are probably missing something in the query.

2)If you got the db data perfectly,then just change the name of returning array in your model.

```
function read()
{        
   $sql = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material');  

   if($sql->num_rows() > 0)
    {     
        foreach($sql->result() as $row)
        {  
            $c_row[] = $row;  
        }     
        return $c_row;  //comment this return part while debugging
        // print_r($c_row);
        //exit;
    } 
    else 
    {  
        return null;  
    }
```

}

Comment: can you tell me where should i place that `print_r($data)` . idk because i was copy pasting the code, and changing some of variable :( and how to load them, since we cannot load a model from the views

Comment: @Cignitor Check the edit.. I commented the `print_r($c_row)` part. Remove the comments,test it and comment it after debugging

Comment: its showing the same error, i am using your function and removed the comment, the same controller and views as shown on the top,

Comment: @Cignitor You didn't exit it.. add this.. `print_r($c_row);exit;` .. Now,check the output and report it

Comment: i've changed the controller into `$data['c_row'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->read();  
        echo $data;` then i load them, it displays a blank page with "array" text

Comment: @Cignitor When you add `exit;` and reload the controller you should either get a blank page or a page with arrays of data. There is no chance of getting an error because you aren't going back to the controller after entering model

Comment: @Cignitor Do one thing,change your `function read()` in the model exactly like the one which i've posted. Then remove `//` from `print_r` and `exit` and comment the `return` part

Comment: @Cignitor instead of doing `echo $data`, give like this `print_r($data)`

Comment: it shows `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ001 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => batu ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ002 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => batu ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ003 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => batu ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ004 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => batu ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ005 [Nama_Material_J`

now how do i pass the entire record into foreach ?

Comment: @Cignitor Well,that's your data! Now you should get it working

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you print your data array to get exact idea of what you are getting in that array. Try following format,  might be helpful

```
function getPosts() {
$query = $this->db->get('posts');
$posts = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $posts[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'title' => $row->title,
        'content' => $row->content
    );
}

return $posts;
}
```

Comment: it returns a blank screen, i have entered some record into the database, and the controller goes like this ` function index()
    {
        $this->m_kategorimaterial->read();
    }`